# nearby location and matching keys locations

Tags: php, google-api

I want to do something like get **nearby location** from given latitude and longitude using google api

and also get list of locations which match passed address text.

I tried https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

```
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362
&rankby=distance&types=food&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

but i can not pass text here,
so how to get combination of both, using lat long get nearby location or by text get matching areas

Let me share my Key

```
key=AIzaSyDizrD38FGzXpxg98cjD7EeoT8XVaY6_Ww
```

please give me any **working url**

**UPDATED:**

I need two api

1)**textsearch**

for that i tried `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=iscon`

but its not giving giving much results (here something I want something like autocomplete but more than 5 results)

2)**nearbyseach**

for that i tried `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?radius=500&location=34.0522,-118.244&key=AIzaSyDizrD38FGzXpxg98cjD7EeoT8XVaY6_Ww`
and its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It may help to filter your results more accurately :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=urlencode('search term ')&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Just use the 'name' parameter to filter your results, pass your query string to the name parameter, it will give you the results related to the searched term.

Comment: i have added key please check

Comment: Check this Url  ::   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?radius=500&location=34.0522,-118.244&name=Los%20Angeles&key=AIzaSyDizrD38FGzXpxg98cjD7EeoT8XVaY6_Ww

Answer (score 1):

Change `type` parameter with `query`,

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?
>     location=-33.8670522,151.1957362
>     &rankby=distance&query=food&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Or you can add `name` filter in the url,

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362%20&rankby=distance&types=food&key=AIzaSyDizrD38FGzXpxg98cjD7EeoT8XVaY6_Ww&name=%22Biaggio%22

Comment: [Check this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=-41.319282,174.818717&radius=1000&sensor=true&ty&key=AIzaSyAhaD4HwgofkA2_9Z7fLbGB1V8Shi-S7do&query=%22Cafe%22) & [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=-41.319282,174.818717&radius=1000&sensor=true&ty&key=AIzaSyAhaD4HwgofkA2_9Z7fLbGB1V8Shi-S7do&query=%22La%20Boca%20Loca%22)

Comment: i have added key please check

Comment: And [working fine](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=-41.319282,174.818717&radius=1000&sensor=true&ty&key=AIzaSyDizrD38FGzXpxg98cjD7EeoT8XVaY6_Ww&query=%22La%20Boca%20Loca%22) with your keys too.

Comment: but now here if i will not pass &query="La Boca Loca" it stoped working

Comment: what i want here is get nearby locations from lat,long or get text match location from world(no any relation of lat,long),have you got my point?

Comment: Yes, you need to call different api based on condition if text call `textsearch` if not call `nearbyseach` make sense ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56318/discussion-between-er-kt-and-rikesh).